# How do I start a jquery function automatically when the page loads, and also maintain it's user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript function using Jquery on my page. I want to make so that it will start this function automatically when the page loads, but so the user can also still interact with the function. It's a function that involves selecting a link that will hide and fadeIn a new div. I am trying to have this happen automatically as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        $('#tablecell1').click((function () {
    var last_image = null;

    return function () {
        if (last_image) {
            $('#tablecell1 .selected').attr('src', last_image).removeClass('selected');
        }

        var $clicked_image = $('img', this);
        last_image = $clicked_image.attr('src');
        $clicked_image.attr('src', 'NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar2_01.gif').addClass('selected');
        $('#img2').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_02.gif');
        $('#img3').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_03.gif');
        $('#img4').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_04.gif');
        $('#img5').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_05.gif');

    }
})());

    $('#tablecell2').click((function () {
    var last_image = null;

    return function () {
        if (last_image) {
            $('#tablecell2 .selected').attr('src', last_image).removeClass('selected');
        }

        var $clicked_image = $('img', this);
        last_image = $clicked_image.attr('src');
        $clicked_image.attr('src', 'NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar2_02.gif').addClass('selected');
        $('#img1').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_01.gif');
        $('#img3').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_03.gif');
        $('#img4').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_04.gif');
        $('#img5').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_05.gif');

    }
})());

    $('#tablecell2').click((function () {
    var last_image = null;

    return function () {
        if (last_image) {
            $('#tablecell2 .selected').attr('src', last_image).removeClass('selected');
        }

        var $clicked_image = $('img', this);
        last_image = $clicked_image.attr('src');
        $clicked_image.attr('src', 'NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar2_02.gif').addClass('selected');
        $('#img1').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_01.gif');
        $('#img3').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_03.gif');
        $('#img4').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_04.gif');
        $('#img5').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_05.gif');

    }
})());

    $('#tablecell3').click((function () {
    var last_image = null;

    return function () {
        if (last_image) {
            $('#tablecell3 .selected').attr('src', last_image).removeClass('selected');
        }

        var $clicked_image = $('img', this);
        last_image = $clicked_image.attr('src');
        $clicked_image.attr('src', 'NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar2_03.gif').addClass('selected');
        $('#img1').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_01.gif');
        $('#img2').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_02.gif');
        $('#img4').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_04.gif');
        $('#img5').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_05.gif');

    }
})());

    $('#tablecell4').click((function () {
    var last_image = null;

    return function () {
        if (last_image) {
            $('#tablecell4 .selected').attr('src', last_image).removeClass('selected');
        }

        var $clicked_image = $('img', this);
        last_image = $clicked_image.attr('src');
        $clicked_image.attr('src', 'NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar2_04.gif').addClass('selected');
        $('#img1').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_01.gif');
        $('#img2').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_02.gif');
        $('#img3').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_03.gif');
        $('#img5').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_05.gif');

    }
})());

    $('#tablecell5').click((function () {
    var last_image = null;

    return function () {
        if (last_image) {
            $('#tablecell5 .selected').attr('src', last_image).removeClass('selected');
        }

        var $clicked_image = $('img', this);
        last_image = $clicked_image.attr('src');
        $clicked_image.attr('src', 'NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar2_05.gif').addClass('selected');
        $('#img1').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_01.gif');
        $('#img2').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_02.gif');
        $('#img3').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_03.gif');
        $('#img4').attr('src','NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_04.gif');

    }
})());


     $('.preview').hide();

  $('#link_1').click(function(){ 
      $('#latest_story_preview1').hide();
       $('#latest_story_preview2').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview3').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview4').hide();
      $('#latest_story_main').fadeIn(800);
  });   

  $('#link_2').click(function(){ 
      $('#latest_story_main').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview2').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview3').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview4').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview1').fadeIn(800);
  });

  $('#link_3').click(function(){ 
      $('#latest_story_main').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview1').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview3').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview4').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview2').fadeIn(800);
  });

    $('#link_4').click(function(){ 
      $('#latest_story_main').hide();
       $('#latest_story_preview1').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview2').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview4').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview3').fadeIn(800);
  });
    $('#link_5').click(function(){ 
      $('#latest_story_main').hide();
       $('#latest_story_preview1').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview2').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview3').hide();
      $('#latest_story_preview4').fadeIn(800);
  });


    });
```

Comment: Why don't you move the code inside document.ready into another function `function foo() { code here }` and then call that in document.ready and wherever else you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) for triggering any event  in code

as

```
  $('#link_1').trigger('click');
```

Comment: This method seems simpler, but how would I add the attribute of triggering it when the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

Give the function a name, then call it where appropriate with arguments.

```
function hideLinkFadeDiv(link, div) {
  link.hide();
  div.fadeIn();
};

$(function() { //Personal Preference Instead of $(document).ready(function() {

  hideLinkFadeDiv($('#foo'), $('#bar'));
  //Runs when the document loads

  $('#foo').on('click', function() { 
    hideLinkFadeDiv($(this), $('#bar'));
    //runs when #foo is clicked
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok I see, so then how would I would adapt to my purposes? Because I need it to keep occurring continually for all DIV's, but still keep the same click function

Answer (score 0):

I left the inner workings of the your provided functions untouched, but you should consider using classes instead of id's.

```
// Once the DOM is ready
$(function(){
    tableClick("1", {"2", "3", "4", "5"});
    tableClick("2", {"1", "3", "4", "5"});
    tableClick("3", {"1", "2", "4", "5"});
    tableClick("4", {"1", "2", "3", "5"});
    tableClick("5", {"1", "2", "3", "4"});

    $('.preview').hide();

    linkClick("1", {"1", "2", "3", "4"});
    linkClick("2", {"0", "2", "3", "4"});
    linkClick("3", {"0", "1", "3", "4"});
    linkClick("4", {"0", "1", "2", "4"});
    linkClick("5", {"0", "1", "2", "3"});
});

// tableClick
var tableClick = function(el, order){
    $("#tablecell" + el).click(function(){
        var last_image = null;

        return function () {
            if (last_image) {
                $(this).find(".selected").attr("src", last_image).removeClass("selected");
            }

            var $clicked_image = $("img", this);
            last_image = $clicked_image.attr("src");
            $clicked_image.attr("src", "NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar2_0" + el +".gif").addClass("selected");
            for (var i = 1; i <= order.length; i++ ){
                $("#img" + order[i]).attr("src","NewsBarAZ/Article-Nav-Bar1_0" + order[i] + ".gif");
            }
        }
    });
};

// linkClick
var linkClick = function(el, hideElements){
    $("#link_" + el).click(function(){
        // hide elements
        for (var i = 0; i < hideElements.length; i++){      
            if (hideElements[i] == "0") $("#latest_story_main").hide();
            else $("#latest_story_preview" + hideElements[i]).hide();
        }

        // show active
        var active = parseInt(el) - 1;

        if (active == 0) active = "main";
        else active = "preview" + active;

        $("#latest_story_" + active).fadeIn(800);
    });
};
```

Comment: How would I implement this to my javascript?

Comment: You can replace your provided code with this

Comment: I did, but it doesn't seem to be working. It loads everything correctly, however when I click a table item it doesn't load it, neither does it replace the image.

Comment: I updated the code. Perhaps you can post some HTML as well since I am unable to debug right now